# Why can I not access CoverArt in Gracenote?

Tags: gracenote

My WEBAPI Query matches the example query but the response does not
contain the following fields. Is this because I am using a "Community
Licence" Non-commercial use?

Album Fields missing

```
XID DATASOURCE
URL TYPE="COVERART" SIZE="MEDIUM" url
URL TYPE="ARTIST_BIOGRAPHY" url
```

Track Fields missing

```
GENRE 
XID DATASOURCE
URL TYPE="ARTIST_BIOGRAPHY" url
```

The Query as per
https://developer.gracenote.com/sites/default/files/web/html/index.html#PDFs/Music-Web-API-Developers-Guide-o.pdf
Page 38

```
"<QUERIES> 
 <AUTH> <CLIENT>$clientID</CLIENT><USER>$userID</USER></AUTH>
 <LANG>eng</LANG>
 <COUNTRY>usa</COUNTRY> 
 <QUERY CMD='ALBUM_SEARCH'>
   <MODE>SINGLE_BEST</MODE>
   <TEXT TYPE='ARTIST'>The Beatles</TEXT> 
   <OPTION> <PARAMETER>SELECT_EXTENDED</PARAMETER>
    <VALUE>COVER,LINK,ARTIST_BIOGRAPHY</VALUE> </OPTION> 
   <OPTION> <PARAMETER>PREFER_XID</PARAMETER>
    <VALUE>applealbumid</VALUE> </OPTION>
 </QUERY> </QUERIES>"
```

RESPONSE from My Query

```
<RESPONSES> 
<RESPONSE STATUS="OK"> 
<ALBUM> 
<GN_ID>a_gracenote_identifier</GN_ID> 
<ARTIST>The Beatles</ARTIST> 
<TITLE>Abbey Road</TITLE> 
<PKG_LANG>ENG</PKG_LANG> 
<DATE>1969</DATE> 
<GENRE NUM="106204" ID="35972">Psychedelic</GENRE> 
<TRACK_COUNT>17</TRACK_COUNT> 
<TRACK> 
<TRACK_NUM>1</TRACK_NUM> 
<GN_ID>a_gracenote_identifier</GN_ID> 
<TITLE>Come Together</TITLE> 
</TRACK> 
...
<TRACK> 
<TRACK_NUM>17</TRACK_NUM> 
<GN_ID>a_gracenote_identifier</GN_ID> 
<TITLE>Her Majesty</TITLE> 
</TRACK> 
</ALBUM> 
</RESPONSE> 
</RESPONSES>
```

EXAMPLE RESPONSE from documentation
https://developer.gracenote.com/sites/default/files/web/html/index.html#PDFs/Music-Web-API-Developers-Guide-o.pdf
Page 38

```
<RESPONSES> 
<RESPONSE STATUS="OK"> 
<ALBUM> 
<GN_ID>a_gracenote_identifier</GN_ID> 
<ARTIST>The Beatles</ARTIST> 
<TITLE>The Beatles (White Album) \ [Disc 1\] </TITLE> 
<DATE>1968</DATE> 
<GENRE NUM="106204" ID="35972">Psychedelic</GENRE> 
<XID DATASOURCE="applealbumid">401126224</XID> 
<TRACK_COUNT>17</TRACK_COUNT> 
<TRACK> 
<TRACK_NUM>1</TRACK_NUM> 
<GN_ID>a_gracenote_identifier</GN_ID> 
<TITLE>Back In The USSR</TITLE> 
<GENRE NUM="64660" ID="27056">60's Oldies</GENRE> 
<XID DATASOURCE="appletrackid">401126225</XID> 
<XID DATASOURCE="gracenote" DATATYPE="isrc">GBAYE0601644</XID> 
<XID DATASOURCE="gracenote" DATATYPE="isrc">GBAYE0900726</XID> 
<URL TYPE="ARTIST_BIOGRAPHY">a_temporary_url</URL> 
</TRACK> 
<TRACK> 
<TRACK_NUM>2</TRACK_NUM> 
<GN_ID>a_gracenote_identifier</GN_ID> 
<TITLE>Dear Prudence</TITLE> 
<GENRE NUM="64660" ID="27056">60's Oldies</GENRE> 
<XID DATASOURCE="appletrackid">401126240</XID> 
<XID DATASOURCE="appletrackid">402094784</XID> 
<XID DATASOURCE="gracenote" DATATYPE="isrc">GBAYE0601645</XID> 
<XID DATASOURCE="gracenote" DATATYPE="isrc">GBAYE0900727</XID>
<URL TYPE="ARTIST_BIOGRAPHY">a_temporary_url</URL> 
</TRACK> 
<TRACK> 
<TRACK_NUM>3</TRACK_NUM> 
<GN_ID>a_gracenote_identifier</GN_ID> 
<TITLE>Glass Onion</TITLE> 
<GENRE NUM="64660" ID="27056">60's Oldies</GENRE> 
<XID DATASOURCE="appletrackid">401126255</XID> 
<XID DATASOURCE="appletrackid">402094792</XID> 
<XID DATASOURCE="gracenote" DATATYPE="isrc">GBAYE0601646</XID> 
<XID DATASOURCE="gracenote" DATATYPE="isrc">GBAYE0900728</XID> 
<URL TYPE="ARTIST_BIOGRAPHY">a_temporary_url</URL> 
</TRACK> 
... 
<URL TYPE="COVERART" SIZE="MEDIUM">a_temporary_url</URL> 
<URL TYPE="ARTIST_BIOGRAPHY">a_temporary_url</URL> 
</ALBUM> 
</RESPONSE> 
</RESPONSES>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are not using the correct type of Client ID.
You need to use a **music platform** Client ID to make WebAPI queries.
Look for your App Detail and check if your Client ID is "**Client ID for Mobile Client, Web API, and eyeQ**".